# Static Initializer in asm

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I want to initialize a static field which I added to a class using asm. If I could access the static initializer then I could to the initialization.

How can I initialize a static field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are adding the field by using a [ClassAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassAdapter.html) that delegates almost everything to a [ClassWriter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html) but also calls [visitField](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html) to add the new fields.

If the fields that you are adding are initialized to constants.  Then you can simply supply an Object literal directly to [ClassVisitor.visitField](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html).

If the fields that you are adding require complicated static initialization, then you need to override [ClassAdapter.visitMethod](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassAdapter.html) check for the `<clinit>` method and create a custom [MethodAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodAdapter.html) that adds your desired code.  A rough sketch of the code is as follows:

```
class MyAdapter extends ClassAdapter {
  public MyAdapter(ClassVisitor delegate) {
    super(delegate);
  }

  @Override
  public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, 
                            String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    MethodVisitor r = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
    if ("<clinit>".equals(name)) {
      r = new MyMethodAdapter(r);
    }
    return r;
  }

  class MyMethodAdapter extends MethodAdapter {
    MyMethodAdapter(MethodVisitor delegate) {
      super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitCode() {
      super.visitCode();
      // build my static initializer by calling
      // visitFieldInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) 
      // or the like
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just override `visitField` in [ClassVisitor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html)